# Flutter - How to control the border width of the circular progress indicator?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been using the `CircularProgressIndicator` class to show a circular progress indicator with `SizedBox` class to control the size of the child widget a while ago,
just like that :

```
...
SizedBox(
  width: 20.0,
  height: 20.0,
  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
    Colors.deepOrange,
    ),
  ),
)
...
```

But i'm encountering that its width is exaggerated ,
Can i reduce the width of that indicator ?

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strokeWidth` property of `CircularProgressIndicator` to define it's width.

```
SizedBox(
 width: 20.0,
 height: 20.0,
   child: CircularProgressIndicator(
     strokeWidth: 2.0,
     valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
       Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
    ),
 )
```